# Adding Manufacturer City and Country in Prestashop 1.6 on Product List and Product Page

Tags: php, prestashop, shopping-cart, cart, prestashop-1.6

I have override ProductController.php as follows in order to display manufactere Country.

```
class ProductController extends ProductControllerCore
{
   public function initContent()
   {
       $manufacturer_country = "";
       if($this->product->id_manufacturer > 0)
       {
           $manufacturer = new Manufacturer($this->product->id_manufacturer, $this->context->language->id);
           $manufacturer_country = $manufacturer->country;
       }

       $this->context->smarty->assign('manufacturer_country', $manufacturer_country);
       parent::initContent();
   }
```

}

in product.tpl i wrote {$manufacturer_country} but nothing print. can anyone guide me how to print on product.tpl and product-list.tpl

Comment: I put above ProductController.php in Project\override\controller\front\ directory. I delete cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Overriding a controller**

The file can be placed in either of these locations:

```
/override/controllers/front/ProductController.php
/modules/my_module/override/controllers/front/ProductController.php
/themes/prestashop/modules/my_module/my_module.tpl
/themes/prestashop/css/modules/my_module/my_module.css
/themes/prestashop/js/modules/my_module/my_module.js
```

You need you adapt your path in your context as the version 1.6 require. Regards

Comment: yes i put it on first path location. but i am not getting print country.

Comment: self::$smarty->assign('currentController', ..);

Comment: you assign to the manufacturer_country and no a new variable "currentController"  i think your error is here, you have 2 sames variables in the same template.

Comment: And disable the cache if you did enabled.

Comment: sorry I have done every thing but still fail to show country. I'm new to php

Comment: Did you create a new module based of that controller without overwriting the core?

Comment: Nope Just make new file /override/controllers/front/ProductController.php with above code.

Comment: Just look at this doc and do at local and overriders/ folder here a good explain https://prestadb.com/prestashop-override-controllers-tutorial/